# How to display a vtable by name using gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, vtable

When debugging where you have a crash dump, vtable pointers are good indicators of an object in memory.

What I would like to do in gdb is be able to query for the vtable by doing something like

```
info address 'vtable for Bar'
```

However, the only way to do this (without requiring a valid instance of the object) I have found is to use the mangled name for the vtable.

Example:

```
info address _ZTV3Bar
```

It isn't the end of the world to try and figure out the vtable mangled name, but it is an annoyance (i.e. using objdump -t myexecutable).

Does anyone know of a way where I can find the vtable address of a type in a less painful way (**without requiring a valid instance of the type**)?
  - Rules: can't require a valid instance of the object in question and find the vtable pointer in the object.

Comment: It could be a silly question, but did you try printing the contents of Bar? For example: `print *barObject`?

Comment: That's against the rules.  I don't have an instance of the object, but simply want to find the vtable for the type.

Comment: It looks like a gdb bug.  "info addr" can complete "vtable for ..." but then it doesn't compute a result properly.  Could you file this in bugzilla?

Comment: `info address vtable for Bar` works for me

Answer (score 6):

Use info variable instead:

> info variable vtable for Bar

Answer (score 3):

Displays information about a virtual method table (vtable) of an object

Syntax

```
info vtbl [Expression]
```

Parameters

Expression
Specifies an expression that will be evaluted to get the pointer to the object which virtual method table should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

> That's against the rules.

Which rules are these?

> I don't have an instance of the object, but simply want to find the vtable for the type.

But you do:

```
set print object on
print *(Bar*) 0x123456
```

This will attempt to print the object at 0x123456 as if it were a `Bar`, or derived from `Bar`. If in fact the object at that location is derived from `Bar`, GDB will deduce the derived type, and print its members.

Comment: But the members and vptr will be incorrect.  If you just arbitrarily pick a memory location and cast it as a bar, it will show that object as a Bar, but the vptr will be incorrect and NOT point to the vtable for Bar.

It would be nice to be able to visually inspect the memory location of 0x123456 and see if the vptr is actually pointing to the vtable for Bar.  But in order to know that address I need to find it somehow, which is the original question

Comment: I agree you can probably do it easily for a single memory location, but if you were browsing through a bunch of memory, it would be useful to be able to visually inspect the memory for vtable pointers rather than try and cast everything one at a time.